# Dynamically changing the Angular $scope variables

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two arrays (scope variables) whose values are getting updated dynamically, but in the HTML when I am trying to print their values, the view is not taking the updated ones.

```
<div>
    <!-- array printing -->
    <span ng-repeat="var in array track by $index">{{var}}</span>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- array -->
    <span ng-repeat="var in array2 track by $index">{{var}}</span>
</div>
```

When I am printing the values in the console log, the array is changing but its changes are not getting reflected in the page.

**controller.js**

```
$scope.update = function() {

    $scope.array.push(box); 

    // inside an ajax call
    var index = $scope.array.indexOf(box);

    if(index > -1) {
        $scope.array.splice(index,1);
        console.log("index "+index);
    }  
}
```

Comment: what is your updating function ?

Comment: On what action array gets updated? Can u pls provide controller js?

Comment: can you provide a plunker or fiddle ?

Comment: in second array, wtf is {{request}} ? :) should be {{var}}

Comment: Sorry, that was {{var}}

Comment: How are you calling `$scope.update`? You probably need to `$scope.$apply` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your Ajax call is not being called by AngularJS. Maybe you're using jQuery?

In this case, try using `$scope.$apply();` after the end of the Ajax callback function. It will verify any changes and update your view variables.

You can read more about `$apply` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) and [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thanks :) I had to call the digest loop.